# Is this a rule in German language that words that end with "stand" always have "der" artikel?

Tags: article, compound

I have a list of quite a few words with such ending and all of them have this Artikel:
*der Widerstand

der Bestand

der Verstand

der Abstand

der Zustand

der Gegenstand

der Stand

der Vorstand

der Erkenntnisstand*

Comment: *[instand](https://www.dwds.de/wb/instand)* is an adverb and does not take an article.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's all derived from one word "Der Stand". So every other word with whatever prefix gets the same gender.

Gender always is determined by the last word in a compound. The gender also doesn't change when the first part of the compound is not a noun in its own right, but a preposition used as prefix.

For example die Erkenntnis + der Stand --> der Erkenntnisstand.

If both parts are nouns, one can possibly create different compound nouns with different meanings, e.g. Die Phantasie + das Auto --> das Phantasieauto (=phantasy car) / die Autophantasie (=car phantasy).

If the first part is a preposition one cannot swap the order and from the meaning it can 'feel' like an entirely new word only very loosely related to the original: Gegen + Stand -> Gegenstand

Comment: While true, it isn't especially helpful because most of the examples in the OP aren't compounds at all. "Verstand", "Bestand", "Abstand" aren't compounds.

Comment: @wonderbear yes-ish. However they are compound in the sense of prefix + noun to a new compound noun. Does that have a different name than 'compound' to name it separately? I was seaching for a word to describe that, but didn't find one.

Comment: I made an edit to point out and explain better these two different ways of creating a compound noun. Does it become better understandable this way?

Comment: As I understand it, this rule also extends to *suffixes* which aren't words on their own, e.g. words ending "-chen" are always neuter, explaining why "das Mädchen" is not grammatically feminine.

Comment: @IMSoP *Diminuitves* are always neuter, and "Mädchen" is the diminutive of "Maid/Magd".

Comment: @rexkogitans I think diminutives are neuter *because* it's the suffix that declines. Editors of Wiktionary clearly think so, producing a [list of suffixes by gender](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:German_suffixes_by_gender); for instance, nouns ending -heit -schaft are feminine. There are a handful there which have multiple genders, but the majority are consistent.

Comment: @IMSoP I'm not sure the rule stated above holds for suffixes. E.g. -nis does not have a unique gender (though -heit, -keit, -tum) do.

Comment: @planetmaker: In German (as in most other European languages) there are a few suffixes with multiple genders, but many more with a fixed gender — enough that it makes sense to think of “the suffix determines the gender” as a rule with some exceptions.

Comment: @rexkogitans Not quite all diminutives are neuter. There are a few which are formed with other suffixes than _-chen_ and _-lein_, and these are not all neuter (e.g., _Setzling_ is masculine).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, and that's a general rule. The more letters at the end match, the more likely two nouns have the same gender.

- der B**and**
- der Br**and**
- der S**and**
- der St**and**
- der T**and**
- der R**and**

BUT there are of course exceptions:

- das B**and**
- das L**and**
- das Pf**and**
- das Gew**and**
- die B**and**
- die H**and**
- die W**and**

So this rule isn't too useful for the *and* ending. But it is for example useful for the *tand* and *rand* endings, as you can see from the above example. And it's also useful for the other four-letter combinations but *wand* and *band*. You can't see that from the examples above but let me assure you it is.

And this is the trick how to guess noun genders. With four or more letters at the end matching, you can be pretty sure the two nouns have the same gender. There are only a very few exceptions to that, e.g. *der Bericht* vs *die Pflicht* vs *das Licht*. This is obviously because *ch* is a digraph that is only one consonant in reality. So it's a "three-sound" combination. Those may still differ in gender. Or the *die Wand* vs *das Gewand* from above. Those two differ because the two words are actually not related but their writing converged over the centuries. And it's similar for *Band* as well. Those are three different nouns whose writing fully converged.

In your examples, the reason why those letters match is of course because those nouns are all derived from *der Stand*. They are prefixed versions of it, and *der Erkenntnisstand* is a compound noun.

Comment: I am not sure whether teaching learners a formal criterion (number of letters) when it the actual criterion is lexicological (whether the ending is a word of its own or not) is  a really good or a really bad idea.

Comment: This is interesting from the perspective of the history of the German language, but it is not useful for anyone learning German.